# How to connect accelerometer, GPS, microphone and a GSM module to a Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, electronics

I am a noob in the Arduino world and have only started reading about it. I have zero experience with Arduino some suggestions to increase my level will also be highly appreciated. But I have a lot of ideas, I want to work on.

I want to measure the velocity and noise levels with the GPS coordinates of a moving vehicle and send it to my phone using gsm or wifi.
Should I include a small LCD also? again suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you are a beginner, do it in steps:

- Get an Arduino Uno
- Get a feeling for MCUs connecting a LED and resistor.
- Connect the buzzer and get it working.
- Disconnect it, connect the display and get it working.
- Same for one sensor.
- Than try multiple sensors.
- Than play with the WIFI module.
- Than combine everything.

The key is to split up your (for a beginner) big project into smaller easier to handle projects.

If you want to add an LCD, depends fully on YOUR requirements; we don't know exactly what you want. If you send all data via WIFI in principle the receiver can display it, but maybe you have a good reason to display it on a display.